# HTML extension doesn't suggest tags

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My extension doesn't work and suggest tags in my project folder
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPGTO.png)

while it can work normally in other files not belonging to that folder.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9eMz.png)

I have restarted, reinstalled, kept enabling and disabling the extension, but things didn't really change.

Comment: Welcome! Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the difference is **Django**, change the languageID of the file